# Proxying a WordPress page from another subdomain

Tags: nginx, wordpress, subdomain

I have an Nginx installed on an Ubuntu server, and I have installed WordPress on `blog.example.com`.

On the WordPress I created a page for gallery which is accessible from `blog.example.com/gallery`.

Now when someone accesses the `gallery.example.com` it should show the content of the `blog.example.com/gallery`. How can I achieve this in Nginx?

Here is what I have tried on nginx server config of `blog.example.com.config`:

```
   location /gallery {
        proxy_pass http://gallery.example.com/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Correct configuration

Your proxy is the wrong way around! It is a proxy from a path to a subdomain; most likely to the same hostname the path is on. If it is with `server_name gallery.example.com`, it currently proxies from `http://gallery.example.com/gallery` to `http://gallery.example.com/`.

To make it proxy from `http://gallery.example.com` to `http://blog.example.com/gallery`:

```
server {
    server_name gallery.example.com;    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://blog.example.com/gallery;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

### Denial-of-service attacks with the current proxy configuration

The full misconfiguration:

```
server {
    server_name gallery.example.com;    
    location /gallery {
        proxy_pass http://gallery.example.com/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

The detail that this misconfiguration is on the same subdomain as it is proxying to makes it interesting, as someone could actually abuse this kind of setup for denial-of-service by accessing an URL which would cause as many internal proxy connections as there are `/gallery` URL parts following each other.

```
http://gallery.example.com/gallery/gallery/gallery/gallery/gallery/.../gallery
=> . . . 
=> http://gallery.example.com/gallery/gallery/gallery/gallery/gallery/gallery
=> http://gallery.example.com/gallery/gallery/gallery/gallery/gallery
=> http://gallery.example.com/gallery/gallery/gallery/gallery
=> http://gallery.example.com/gallery/gallery/gallery
=> http://gallery.example.com/gallery/gallery
=> http://gallery.example.com/gallery
=> http://gallery.example.com/
```

Invoking many such requests causes high load on the server that can continue long after the attack has been stopped, as the Nginx is still trying to serve all those nested proxy connections. Nginx could also start showing `502 Bad Gateway` & `500 Internal Server Error` for legitimate users.

Even logging all those request could become a problem: `[alert] 1620#1620: *2748894 write() to "/var/log/nginx/access.log" was incomplete: 3421 of 4566 while logging request`

If this was a `https://` server, all those TLS handshakes would have caused even higher loads.

##### How many proxy connection could be caused by a single HTTP request?

The [`large_client_header_buffers`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers) controls the maximum request line length, defaulting to `4 8k` i.e. 8096 ASCII characters. Although [`http2_max_field_size`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#http2_max_field_size) is obsolete, a quick test with `curl` reveals that by default Nginx could serve up to 11157 character long URLs over HTTP/2. Whichever is the limit, your proxy would allow from 1011 to 1394 times `/gallery` in the URL before giving the `414 Request-URI Too Large` error.

A limit of [`worker_connections`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections) gets likely hit first if not increased from the default `512`. That would cause an `500 Internal Server Error` and error log lines containing:

```
512 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream
```